# How to add two Namespaces to an Element using XMLService?

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, xml-namespaces

I need to create an XML Element as follows using XMLService:

```
<serv:message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
              xmlns:serv="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service">
```

I know I can add one namespace using the following Google Apps Script code, but how do I add two namespaces?

```
  var ns = XmlService.getNamespace("serv", "http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service");
  var root = XmlService.createElement("message", ns);
  root.setNamespace(ns);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't declare multiple namespaces in the same element with current XmlServices. We hope Google could implement an similar `addNamespace` method in the future, but that's not in the case. You can only declare one namespace for each element. Sample code according to [W3schools XML Namespaces code.](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)

```
<root>

<h:table xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>Apples</h:td>
    <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:table>

<f:table xmlns:f="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
  <f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name>
  <f:width>80</f:width>
  <f:length>120</f:length>
</f:table>

</root>
```

Create the XML:

```
function createXml() {
  var nsh = XmlService.getNamespace('h', 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/');
  var nsf = XmlService.getNamespace('f', 'http://www.w3schools.com/furniture');

  var root = XmlService.createElement('root');
  var document = XmlService.createDocument(root);

  var child1 = XmlService.createElement('table').setNamespace(nsh);
  var tr = XmlService.createElement('tr').setNamespace(nsh);
  var td1 = XmlService.createElement('td').setNamespace(nsh).setText('Apples');
  var td2 = XmlService.createElement('td').setNamespace(nsh).setText('Bananas');
  tr.addContent(td1).addContent(td2);
  child1.addContent(tr);
  root.addContent(child1);

  var child2 = XmlService.createElement('table').setNamespace(nsf);
  var property1 = XmlService.createElement('name').setNamespace(nsf).setText('Affrican Coffee Table');
  var property2 = XmlService.createElement('width').setNamespace(nsf).setText('80');
  var property3 = XmlService.createElement('length').setNamespace(nsf).setText('120');
  child2.addContent(property1).addContent(property2).addContent(property3);
  root.addContent(child2);

  var xml = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(document);
 }
```

Comment: Looks like there is a open issue re: this in the Google Apps Script issue tracker: 
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3119

Answer (score 2):

If any one is still facing this problem, you can use the parse method like in this example where I set two namespaces atom and gd:

```
var document = XmlService.parse("<atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'></atom:entry>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on KLiFF's suggestion it go's like this.

```
function createSepaXML() {
    var painNamespace = XmlService.parse("<Document xmlns='urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'></Document>");
    var root = painNamespace.getRootElement();
    var CstmrDrctDbtInitn = XmlService.createElement('CstmrDrctDbtInitn');
    root.addContent(CstmrDrctDbtInitn);
    var xml = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(root);
    Logger.log(xml);
```

Answer (score 1):

You normally declare the *xsi* namespace in order to specify the *schemaLocation*. If you do so, the *xsi* namespace will be added:

```
var xsi = XmlService.getNamespace('xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
var serv = XmlService.getNamespace('serv', 'http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service');
var root = XmlService.createElement('message', serv)
  .setAttribute('schemaLocation', 'http://url.of.my schema.xsd', xsi);
var document = XmlService.createDocument(root);
var xml = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(document);
console.log(xml);
```

Console output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<serv:message xmlns:serv="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://url.of.my/schema.xsd" />
```